# Import an .apklib in Eclipse without Maven?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, apklib

I have recently been playing around with some Android `.apklib`s **with** Maven as explained nicely [off](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib) and [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190932/how-do-i-use-android-libraries-apklibs-with-maven-and-eclipse) Stackoverflow

I am very much satisfied with how it works and I had it running on a previously available `Maven` project in a matter of minutes

But I also have projects in which I do **not** work with `Maven`, and I'm sure I am not the only one. So it is somewhat weird to me that I did not find a single thread where someone asked how this is done

**How can I import an existing .apklib in an Android project, specifically in eclipse *without* using Maven?**

Again, I am not looking to *create* an apklib or something like that. I just want to use it inside a standard project.
It seems I am a little blind, if I overlooked something during my search please share a link

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use apklib package, just create your library project as normal project, then add it as library project to your main project.

In eclipse, like this 
 [image]

Or

1. extract apklib,
2. import it as new project,
3. add dependence as above

Comment: I know how to add libraries. I **do** want to use the apklib, I'm sorry but the primary assumption of your answer is wrong

Comment: apklib is one package type, you need to ues it with build system like maven, gradle. I guess it is impossible add dependence like jar in eclipse.